# Output 2d Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a piece of Java code that I want to output in appropriate rows and columns. How to do it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] txt = {{"test","test2"},
                          {"test3","test4"}};
```

I want it to display like this:

test test2

test3 test4

(Really appreciate any help...)

Comment: could you at least give it an attempt? First hint: it will require two loops.

Comment: please show your effort.

Comment: System.out.println(txt[0][0]+" "+txt[0][1]+"\n"+txt[1][0]+" "+txt[1][1]);

(But there should be a better way)

Comment: @user1924813 Better is what way?  Also add your comment to your question as an edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can make use of Lambdas and Streams to get the desired output.

Code:

```
Arrays.stream(txt).forEach(row -> {
    Arrays.stream(row).forEach(element -> {
        System.out.print(element);
        System.out.print("\t");
    });
    System.out.println();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] txt = {{"test","test2"},
                          {"test3","test4"}};

        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < txt[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(txt[i][j]);
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean j < txt[i].length instead of txt[0].

Comment: Thanks @ffhighwind for pointing it out. You are right. Updated the answer.

Comment: We do not have to give the answer to someone who is at last not trying to write the code by himself. I am sure that with just one simple google search he can find the solution. We are making new developers lazy and that is bad for them :(

Comment: Sorry for being lazy? The solution is almost there Jagrut, thanks. I'll figure it out...

Comment: The variable `i` is iterating through the rows, each of which is a one-dimensional array. The variable `j` is iterating through the columns, each of which is a value. A `tab` character separates the column values. Once a row is processed, a `newline` character is output. Hope this helps with understanding what the loops are doing.